# Making outer directory before docker compose build

Tags: bash, docker-compose, directory, yaml

Everything works fine in my docker-compose .yml file, but I can not find the way to implement here simple bash command `sudo mkdir -p /store/pg12/data` or establish `APP_DATA_DIR` PATH variable (my OS is Linux, of course).

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  postgres12:
    container_name: pg12_1212
    image: postgres:12
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1212:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=appdata
      - POSTGRES_USER=appadmin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345678
    volumes: 
      - app_pg12_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./datastore/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
      - ./datastore/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql
      - ./datastore/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3.sql

volumes:
   app_pg12_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: /store/pg12/data
      o: bind
```

Should I use some complicated Dockerfile to execute such a simple bash scripts with effect outside the container ? It would be nice not to have to write CLI scripts manually when building the application data infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reflection, in my opinion the best way is separate bash script is launched by CLI command ex. `sudo ./install.sh` and after preparing the file infrastructure calling docker-compose.yml

```
!/bin/bash
PG_DIR="/store/pg12/data"
DC_FILE="./project-compose-file-directory/docker-compose.yml"
if [[ ! -d "$PG_DIR"  && -f "$DC_FILE" ]]
  then
    echo "Preparing local data storage directory in ${PG_DIR}..."
    sudo mkdir -p "$PG_DIR"
    echo "About to build docker using ${DC_FILE} from ${PWD}" 
    sudo docker-compose -f "$DC_FILE" up -d
    sudo docker ps
    sudo docker volume ls
    # maven clean install project commands ... 
  else
    echo "Installation aborted!"  
fi
```

docker-compose.yml is unsuitable to make any directory outside the docker.